# Problemas para atualizar dados com DateTime vazio

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso de ajuda com o seguinte...

Preciso atualizar diversos dados de uma vez através da minha aplicação, porém, uma das condições é que o campo **saida** no banco de dados esteja vazio, pois é ele que será atualizado. O campo em questão é do tipo *DateTime*.

Segue código sql:

```
UPDATE fluxo SET saida = SAIDA WHERE data = DATA AND saida = NULL
```

No caso, eu preciso atualizar um grande numero de saídas que não foram preenchidas de modo simultâneo. Se eu retirar a condição **saida = NULL** ele atualiza todos os dados de uma vez daquela data, o que não deve ser feito.

Utiizando tanto NULL quanto aspas vazias, o resultado é o mesmo: nada acontece.

Agradeço a ajuda e a atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para verificar um valor **NULL** utilize aos operadores **IS NULL** e **IS NOT NULL**.

**Exemplo:**

```
UPDATE `fluxo`
SET `saida` = '2017-09-21'
WHERE `data` = '2017-01-01' AND `saida` is null
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95ac48/1)

Referência

- [Trabalhando com Valores NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado...